# Getting errors whilst trying to map card with its image

Tags: java, arraylist

so essentially the problem is I am perfectly able to deal a card, I am just unable to display said card in theFrame. What should happen is every time the user wants a card to be dealt, it will display in the console window and also the image of the card will be displayed in theFrame. The image's themselves are titled "5d.gif" or "ah.gif" which correspond with the output in the console window, as when a user asks to be dealt a card the card dealt is then displayed in the format "5d" or "ah". I am simply missing the part where the card dealt, I am fairly confident that I am close to obtaining a solution, based on the map solution that was suggested by commenters on my last post on here. I am experiencing a few errors in TheFrame class, "cards" in the cardDisplay method "can't be resolved to a variable". Also, in the paintComponent method, "image" also "can't be resolved to a variable". Also, in my Game class, under my drawCards method it says that cardDisplay "is undefined for type TheFrame". I have put my 4 classes below to better show what's going on:

Card -

```js
    package uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards;

 public class Card {
 public String number;
 public String suit;

 public Card(String n, String s) {
  number = n;
  suit = s;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return number + suit;
 }

}
```

Game -

```js
     import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;
import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.gui.TheFrame;

public class Game {

 private Scanner scan;
 private Deck deck;
 private TheFrame frame;
 private ArrayList<Card> onTable = new ArrayList<Card>();

 public Game() {
  frame = new TheFrame();
  deck = new Deck();
  try {
   deck.buildDeck();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.err.println("Error reading in deck...");
   System.exit(-1);
  }

 }

 private void runMenu() throws IOException {

  String response;
  do {
   printMenu();
   System.out.println("What would you like to do:");
   scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   response = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();
   switch (response) {
   case "1":
    PrintDeck();
    break;
   case "2":
    ShuffleCards();
    break;
   case "3":
    DealCard();
    break;
   case "4":
    MoveToPrevious();
    break;
   case "5":
    Move2PilesBack();
    break;
   case "6":
    AmalgamateInMiddle();
    break;
   case "7":
    PlayforMe();
    break;
   case "8":
    ShowLowScores();
   case "Q":
    break;
   default:
    System.out.println("Try again");

   }
   drawCards();

  } while (!(response.equals("Q")));
 }

 private void ShowLowScores() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void PlayforMe() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void AmalgamateInMiddle() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void Move2PilesBack() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void MoveToPrevious() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 private void DealCard() {
  Card c = deck.removeTopCard();

  System.out.println(c);
 }

 private void ShuffleCards() {

  deck.shuffle();

 }

 private void drawCards() {
  ArrayList<String> visibleCards = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (Card card : onTable) {
   visibleCards.add(card.number + card.suit + ".gif");
    
  }
   
  frame.cardDisplay(visibleCards);
   
 }

 private void PrintDeck() throws IOException {
  for (Card card : deck.getDeck()) {
   System.out.println(card);
  }

 }

 private void printMenu() {

  System.out.println("1 -  Print the pack ");
  System.out.println("2 -  Shuffle");
  System.out.println("3 -  Deal a card");
  System.out.println("4 -  Move last pile onto previous one");
  System.out.println("5 -  Move last pile back over two piles");
  System.out.println("6 -  Amalgamate piles in the middle");
  System.out.println("7 -  Play for me");
  System.out.println("8 -  Show low scores");
  System.out.println("q - Quit");

 }

 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  System.out.println("****Welcome to patience is virtue****");
  Game cardsgame = new Game();
  cardsgame.runMenu();
  System.out.println("****Thanks for playing****");
 }
}
```

Deck -

```js
  

  import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;

public class Deck {
 private ArrayList<Card> cards;

 public Deck() {
  cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
 }

 public void buildDeck() throws IOException {

  List<String> cardLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("cards.txt"));
  for (int i = 0; i < cardLines.size(); i += 2) {
   // System.out.println()
   cards.add(new Card(cardLines.get(i), cardLines.get(i + 1)));

  }
 }

 public Card removeTopCard() {
  return cards.remove(0);
 }

 public List<Card> getDeck() {
  return cards;
 }

 public void shuffle() {
  Collections.shuffle(cards);
  System.out.println(cards);
 }

}
```

TheFrame-

```js
     package uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import uk.ac.aber.dcs.cs12320.cards.Card;
 
public class TheFrame extends JFrame {

 public static boolean paintComponent;
 private ThePanel canvas;

 /**
  * The constructor creates a Frame ready to display the cards
  */
 public TheFrame() {

  // Calls the constructor in the JFrame superclass passing up the name to 
  // display in the title
  super("Becky's Patience");
  
  // When you click on the close window button the window will be closed
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  
  // This has North, East, South, West and Center positions for components
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  // This is what we will draw on (see the inner class below)
  canvas = new ThePanel(null);
  setSize(700, 300);
  this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  setVisible(true); // Display the window
 }

 /**
  * Displays all cards
  * 
  * @param cards
  *            an arraylist of strings of the form 3h.gif for 3 of hearts
  */
 /*public void cardDisplay(ArrayList<String> cards) {
  canvas.cardDisplay(cards);
 }*/
 
 /**
  * Call before cardDisplay at end of game (takes away the unused pile)
  */
 public void allDone() {
  canvas.allDone();
 }

 // /////////////////////////////////////////////////

 /*
  * This is an example of an inner class (like Russian dolls)
  * It private so can only be seen by the outer class. It's part
  * of the implementation of TheFrame. Because it extends JPanel we
  * can draw on it
  */
 
 Map<Card, Image> loadCards(ArrayList<Card> cards)
    {
       Map<Card, Image> cardImages = new HashMap<>();
       for (Card card : cards) 
       {
            String file = "cards/" + card.number + card.suit + ".gif";
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
            cardImages.put(card, image);
       }
       return cardImages;
    }
 
 private class ThePanel extends JPanel {
  private Map<Card, Image> cardImages;
     private ArrayList<Card> currentCardDisplayed;
     private boolean done;

     private ThePanel(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
       setBackground(Color.cyan);
       done = false;
       cardImages = loadCards(cards);
  }

  private void cardDisplay(ArrayList<String> c) {
   cards = c;
   repaint();
  }

  private void allDone() {
   done = true;
  }

  /**
   * This is called automatically by Java when it want to draw this panel.
   * So we have to put our drawing command in here. 
   * @param g Is the graphics object on which we draw.
   */
  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // Always do this. It's giving the JPanel superclass a change to
   // paint its parts before we paint ours. E.g. we don't draw the
   // edge of the window, one of the super-classes does that.
   super.paintComponent(g);
   int x = 20;
   int y = 50;
   // Loop through all the cards get each image in turn
   for (Card card: currentCardDisplayed) {
       g.drawImage(cardImages.get(card), x, y, 70, 100, this);
    x += 72;  // The x position is moved on in order to position the next card
              // This could be improved by having a horizontal scroll bar
   }
   if (!done) {
    // Draws the face-down top card of our pack of cards
    String file = "cards/b.gif";
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
    g.drawImage(image, 100, 152, 70, 100, this);
   }
  }
 } // ThePanel inner class
```

Here's where I'm trying to map the gifs from:
[image: Here's where I'm trying to map the gifs from:]
Here's what currently happens when I press case 3 in my GUI to deal a card (currently not running due to errors, however):
[image: What currently happens:]

Thanks for any help in fixing the errors I currently have, I'm confident I'm close to a solution for displaying a card on the frame based on the GUI card that has been dealt.

Comment: Why is the `cardDisplay` method commented out in `TheFrame`?

Comment: This looks a lot like someone else's code that you are trying to run. If you already know the errors, why can't you fix them yourself? I feel this question is off-topic and not helpful for anyone else and should be closed.

Comment: It's for an assignment, we were provided with one class, theFrame class and we have to design the rest of the program to meet requirements. I have tried editing TheFrame class without fully understanding how to intergrate it with my code, which is why I'm having problems. Also copeg, I commented it out because it was causing more errors to appear.

Answer (score 1):

This looks **a lot** like homework... so I'll keep my answer a little conceptual.

Basically you have this deck of cards that you want to remove cards from, and have other parts of your application to respond when that *event* happens.  There are generally two patterns to handle this situation.

You could use a messaging framework where `DealCard` removes the top card, and then posts a message to some sort of bus that then let's everyone that wants to know about this message: here is the card drawn.  Then you'd have your `TheFrame` and something else that handles the console handle the cards.  I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, so maybe that's a little over the top... if it's not here's the messaging library I like (bonus works nicely with Android: http://square.github.io/otto/)

The other thing you may want to do is create an interface something like

```
public interface CardDrawnListener {
    void onCardDrawn(final Card card);
}
```

Then have your deck keep track of a `List<CardDrawnListeners>`.  Then you need to have the frame add a new `CardDrawnListener` and something that handles the console (which you could do in-line like you have it).

Now your `TheFrame` will know whenever a card is drawn from the deck and can do whatever it wants with it.  With this pattern be very careful to not replicate state (keep track of which cards are in the deck) in lots of places... the `Deck` is the place that knows about which cards are in the deck and which are not.

**Compile Error Problems:**

> errors in TheFrame class, "cards" in the cardDisplay method "can't be resolved to a variable"

The variable `cards` is the parameter passed into `ThePanel`, and not stored as member variables anywhere... I assume you either want to have a member variable (`private List<String> cards` on `ThePanel` or you want to not store that state...)

> in the paintComponent method, "image" also "can't be resolved to a variable"

There is no variable `image`, so you just need to define a local variable there.  Should be as easy as changing:

```
image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
```

to

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file);
```

> in my Game class, under my drawCards method it says that cardDisplay "is undefined for type TheFrame"

It's saying that you are trying to call the method `cardDisplay` on your `TheFrame` object, but that's not a method on that object.  So you should go into `TheFrame` and make a method called `cardDisplay`.  That method probably wants to just call `ThePanel`s `cardDisplay` method.

Comment: While this will definitely help the OP, I am not sure how this answers the question. `I am experiencing a few errors in TheFrame class, "cards" in the cardDisplay method "can't be resolved to a variable". Also, in the paintComponent method, "image" also "can't be resolved to a variable". Also, in my Game class, under my drawCards method it says that cardDisplay "is undefined for type TheFrame"`

Comment: That's a good point, I'll update my address those individual compile errors... it's a homework assignment so I was more taking on the "how to solve your problems" than spoon feeding answers...